# Validate certain parameters in every WebMethod

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

I am working on a simple web service based on .NET4

Most of my WebMethods look like this

```
    [WebMethod]
    public List<Customer> GetCustomers(Country country, Guid sessionId)
    {
        if (!Validate(sessionId)
            return null;
        ...
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public List<Order> GetOrders(Customer customer, Guid sessionId)
    {
        if (!Validate(sessionId)
            return null;
        ...
    }
```

As you can see the web methods need to validate a given session id before doing the real work. Since I am going to have several of such WebMethods, I am afraid to miss the Validate() call in a couple of WebMethods.

Do I have any chance to intercept and validate a given sessionId *before* the relevant WebMethods gets executed? And return Null (or whatever) in case the validation failed - so the relevant WebMethod is not even called?

Thanks for any idea (code snippet greatly appreciated!)
Ingmar

Answer (score 0):

[ASMX Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164100.aspx) using [SoapExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soapextension.aspx), [SoapExtensionReflector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.description.soapextensionreflector.aspx), [SoapExtensionImporter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.description.soapextensionimporter.aspx)

**Doing same in WCF is so easy** therefore providing an example :)

[WCF Sample](http://winterdom.com/2006/09/iparameterinspectorinwcf) using [IParameterInspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iparameterinspector.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. And yes, working with attributes is probably a cleaner way to handle this than what I did. But I am still forced to decorate *every* single method with such attributes. However, I was rather looking for something "on a higher" level, e.g. class constructor or something. But maybe I missed a point?

Comment: `Do I have any chance to intercept and validate a given sessionId before the relevant WebMethods gets executed` part of question can only be answered with usage of attributes. Also check [Unity](http://unity.codeplex.com/) that may be you might be looking for.